# How to run the script both 'on load' and 'on resize' (on a particular window width!) in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my current website project I've integrated [Alvaro Trigo's FullPage plugin](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) but since it had a very uncommon behaviour on mobile devices (also due to my project's design requirements), I've decided to switch it off when the viewport width is below 768px. For this purpose I just add a simple if-statement to the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if ($(window).width() > 768 ) {

  $('#fullpage').fullpage({

      // code... code... code...

  });
}

});
```

The problem is that it only takes effect after refreshing the page; so when I go below 768px and reload the page the plugin is switched off, but when I then resize the browser above the mentioned breakpoint, it's still off (and vice versa). I think I should add some lines of code dealing with resize, but unfortunately my current knowledge of JS/jQ doesn't let me do that.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: `$(window).width()` is bad habit to check for viewport width, use instead `window.matchMedia`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia Here polyfill to support older browsers:  https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

  if ($(window).width() > 768 ) {

    //do your thing here

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).resize(function(){ /* do stuff*/ })` instead.
You can then use $(document).trigger('resize') on `onload`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `resize` event. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

Put your code, what you want to do into a function. Call that function on `document ready` with `$(function() {});`, and when you resize the window.

```
$(function () {
    function doSomething() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                //The code
            });
    }

    $(window).resize(function () {
        //Do it on resize
        if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            doSomething();
        }
    });
    //Do it when page loads.
    doSomething();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've actually tried it out already, and the problem is that if I do so, the plugin is never loaded.

Comment: Resize event can be called many many times. Here on each call if condition reached, you are initializing plugin

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to run an anonymous function both when `DOM ready` fires and when `on resize` fires:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        //code to run
    })
    .trigger('resize');
});
```